# Prove the matrix norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove if $A$ is invertible and $\|A-B\|<\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$, then
\begin{align*}
\|A^{-1}-B^{-1}\|\leq \|A^{-1}\|\frac{\|I-A^{-1}B\|}{1-\|I-A^{-1}B\|}
\end{align*}
I know that $\|A-B\|<\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ implies $\|I-A^{-1}B\|<1$, but don't know where to go from here. The norm is  $\|A\|:= \|A\|_\infty := \max_i \sum_j |a_{ij}|$.

Comment: It is not clear to me how a strict inequality ($<$) could imply a possible equality ($\leq$). Could the OP check if the presented enunciate is correct?

Comment: I posted some developments, but I could not achieve the expected answer. After you check if there are no typos in the question, I will try to obtain the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything here is invertible, we have that:

$$\left[I-A^{-1}\,B\right] \left[I-B^{-1}\,A\right] = \left[I-A^{-1}\,B\right] + \left[I - B^{-1}\,A\right] \\
\Rightarrow \\
[I-B^{-1}\,A] = \left[\left[I-A^{-1}\,B\right] - I\right]^{-1} \left[I-A^{-1}\,B\right] \\
\Rightarrow \\
\left\|I-B^{-1}\,A\right\| \leq \left\|\left[I-\left[I-A^{-1}\,B\right]\right]^{-1}\right\| \left\|I-A^{-1}\,B\right\|$$

Therefore:

$$\left\|A^{-1} - B^{-1}\right\| = \left\|\left[I - B^{-1}\,A\right]A^{-1} \right\| \leq \left\|A^{-1}\right\| \left\|I - B^{-1}\,A\right\|$$

Which result in:

$$\left\|A^{-1} - B^{-1}\right\|\leq \left\|A^{-1}\right\| \left\|I-A^{-1}\,B\right\| \left\|\left[I-\left[I-A^{-1}\,B\right]\right]^{-1}\right\|$$

---

The condition $\|A-B\| < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$ imply:

- $\|I - A^{-1}\,B\| < 1$
- $\|A^{-1}\,B\| < 2$
- $\|A-B\| < \|A\|$
- $\|A^{-1} - B^{-1}\| < \|B^{-1}\|$